# Committing third-party libraries to Drupal's CVS, even if they are GPL

Tags: drupal

I want to submit a module to Drupal.org, but my module uses a 'Zip File' class  which is licensed under GPL (http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3864-PHP-Create-and-extract-ZIP-archives-in-purely-in-PHP.html). According to http://drupal.org/cvs-application/requirements, we can not commit a 3rd party lib to Drupal even if it is licensed under GPL, but on the other hand http://drupal.org/node/422996 says that we can use commit 3rd party lib if it is under GPL. So I am confused about the policy. Can anyone please elaborate Drupal's policy for committing 3rd party libs?

I am using http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3864-PHP-Create-and-extract-ZIP-archives-in-purely-in-PHP.html because I could not find any pure PHP implementation of compression utility, and I can't use the ZipArchive class as the required extension can not be enabled on server that I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both pages are pretty clear: regardless of the license, you cannot commit any third-party libraries to the repository. The *only* exceptions are listed:

> 1. had to be modified to work with Drupal and the modifications were not accepted by the original author.
> 2. is generally difficult to find in the needed version.
> 3. is no longer maintained by the original author.

If you think the library you want to commit meets one of those exceptions, it *must* be approved by administrators. You can file an issue on the [Drupal.org Webmasters queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters?status=All&categories=All).

Most of the time, asking users to download a third-party library is not considered an unnecessary hardship. You should also consider integrating with the [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) in case other module authors need to use the same library in the future.